# Editing the pad control register has no effect

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack

After reading the AM3359 Technical Reference manual, I saw that you can edit the pad control registers(Pin Mux). I tried editing these registers using devmem2 and it says that it successfully writes to it but upon reading the value again it is exactly the same.

I used the command `sudo devmem2 0x44E10818 w 0x7` and returns

```
Value at address 0x44E10818 (0xb6f2c818): 0x31
Written 0x7; readback 0x7
```

but then I read it again and it says the value is: 0x31.
All I could think is that maybe there is something underlying in the linux kernel that is setting the values. What is causing the pin mux to hold its value?

Comment: Try to build (with ARM toolchain) and use [omapconf](https://github.com/omapconf/omapconf) for changing register value. Maybe something is wrong with your `devmem2` tool. It's very unlikely that something in kernel rewrites this register all the time. Usually pin muxes are configured one time as part of kernel boot process, using pin mux values from device tree file for your board.

Comment: I'll see how the omapconf does. I will add that I created a c program to read and write to the memory. It could read the pin status but when I would write to the register, it would also have no effect on the it.

Comment: Had a whole lot more trouble with omapconf. Also, I don't think it is a problem with devmem2 because my C program had the same problem. I can't figure out what could be setting those values other than maybe a dtbo file. Ill try to update the kernel to a more recent version and see if that has any effect

Comment: What kind of troubles did you have? From my experience, `omapconf` is general approach for dealing with hardware from shell for developer on OMAP-based platforms. And I see that `omapconf` has support for AM3359. You just need to cross-compile it, upload it to your device and then do something like `omapconf write 0x44E10818 0x7`.

Comment: I had trouble with compiling the program at first but I got it. Unfortunately, this program had the exact same problem. It ran through but didn't change the value.  After some digging around, the kernel that this processor is running comes from https://github.com/RobertCNelson . I'm going see if there is a arm7 kernel that contains no "extras".

Comment: Which revision of BeagleBone Black do you have?

Comment: I have rev A6 on this board. In putting a Debian image on it current. The one that ships with the new boards to see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

From [AM335x TRM](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spruh73) I can see that:

- `0x44E10000` is the address of Control Module registers bank (from section 2 "Memory Map")
- `0x818` is `conf_gpmc_ad6` (from section 9 "Control Module")

From [AM335x datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/am3359) I see that:

- `GPMC_AD6` pad is `R9` ball (for `ZCZ` SoC, which you have on BBB)

From [BBB Rev. A6 schematics](https://github.com/CircuitCo/BeagleBone-Black/blob/rev_a6/BBB_SCH.pdf?raw=true) I see that:

- `R9` ball is connected to `MMC1_DAT6` line
- `MMC1_DAT6` line is connected to eMMC flash

From your question (using TRM) I can conclude that:

- by default this pin is muxed in `mmc1_dat6` mode
- you are trying to remux it to `gpio1_6` mode

So from this investigation I can say that you shouldn't remux that pin (even if it was possible), because it's needed to be muxed as `mmc1_dat6` for eMMC to be accessible from your SoC.

If you are really needed to mux it as `gpio1_6`, be sure to change mux mode for it in device tree file first (and replace `dtb` file on BBB with new one). In that case you won't be able to use [8-bit mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#Table) for your eMMC, so you probably need to change this mode to 4-bit in device tree file as well.

---

References:

[1] [AM3359 SoC documentation](http://www.ti.com/product/AM3359/technicaldocuments)

[2] [BeagleBone Black (Rev. A6) documentation (schematics, etc.)](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#OLD_PRODUCTION_FILES_.28A6.29)

Comment: After reading the answer I chose a few pins that would not interfere with the system and all the pins that I tried to change the MUX of were not changed. I tried omapconf, devmem2, and my C program. All did not change the MUX. I'm still doing research to see what could possibly cause this. I also flashed the original software and kernel that ships with new releases of the beaglebone which also had the same effect.

Comment: That link intended for earlier BeagleBone boards (not BBB), so it's kinda outdated.

Comment: Try sysfs approach described in next posts: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025119/beaglebone-gpio-input-not-working), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892485/how-can-i-edit-a-pinmux-for-beaglebone-black-on-linux-kernel-3-17). If it will not work, try to change pin muxes in your `dts` file, compile it to `dtb`, and flash it to your BBB. Anyway, modifying `dts` (device tree) would be the most correct way to do it. Still it seems weird to me that `omapconf` way doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was trying to create a library that would allow the use of only editing registers, to make it easier and faster to use, unfortunately the system doesn't allow for this. I have read various time that the uboot and the kernel are the only things that can set and change the MUX. After the kernel only software can change it. I'll probably use the file system way, but continue to look into the kernel. Thank you for all your help!